# Cannot reinstall Libreoffice in Appcenter (broken uninstall ?)

Tags: libreoffice

Here's what I get when I try to uninstall/install. I tried with various apt-get purge/clean commands but same happens...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to mark as answered please, so people facing similar can try:

```
 sudo apt-get install libreoffice-writer
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I didn't know the exact name of the package, but apt-get install libreoffice-writer helped and re-linked everything in app center.